# Copying files to NTFS mounted drives

Tags: batch-file, copy, ntfs, usb-drive

I am currently testing over 30 devices at a time and as such I am having to mount the devices as NTFS folders.  I can manually carry out my tests but I have been looking for a way to speed up this process and wrote the following short bat files to carry out this procedure.

```
for /d %%a in ("C:\MP3\*") do start xcopy /e "C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\MP3" "%%a"
```

Unfortunately when I run the batch file although it copies the files, it unmounts the drives and just turns them in to standard folders?

Why would this be happening?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Your code is copying stuff on c: and using wildcards on c: - show us your script that is mounting the folders and explain what you are trying to copy and where to.

Comment: I have manually mounted the USB drives in NTFS Directories ranging 1 to 30 inside the MP3 directory; I am then testing the size of the Devices with an appropriate sized directory copied to each one. once the file has been transfered and confirmed the size of the device I then Delete the directory and copy across the instructions.

Comment: You are testing the size of the USB drive by copying a folder?  There are ways to get the exact size of the devices.

Comment: Yes as these drives can malfunction when full showing over the disk capacity when full, e.g 11gb when disk is only 7.7gb and creating random folders.

Comment: You should get reliable drives, not counterfeit USB drives. We can't see your script so guessing is all we can do as to why your drives change status.

Comment: There not counter fit drives, I have been employed to test devices prior to sales. full code i'm using is above but also use two other batch files coding below, I repeat I mount the drives manually though disk management on windows 7. for /d %%a in ("C:\MP3\*") do start rmdir /s /q "%%a\MP3Upload" and for /d %%a in ("C:\MP3\*") do start copy "C:\MPF\MP4FIN\Instructions.txt" "%%a". If I was only doing one drive at a time I would not have a problem. what I am doing is testing 30+ at a time.